# Community Promotion Ads - 2012

Tags: discussion, community-ads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Community Promotion Ads - 2013](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2484/community-promotion-ads-2013)

Congratulations on graduating into a full-fledged site. This now enables your community to participate in our Community Promotion Ads program!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- interesting articles or findings for the curious
- cool Science Fiction or Fantasy events/conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/991).

Answer (score 14):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is an example base ad, for the site's twitter account, to demonstrate how an answer looks.

Answer (score 13):

[image: Check out our video content!]

Answer (score 12):

[image: Writing exercise chat]

Comment: This is an ad for Writers.SE if you folks are cool with it. We figured there's going to be some interest here in writing, so SFF seemed to be a natural for this.

Answer (score 9):

[image: Sneaky little hobbitses]

Comment: I'd suggest to increase the font size to make it readable.

Comment: @bitmask is that better? Any bigger and the text wont fit on there.

Comment: Yes. That's better.

Answer (score 9):

[image: Space Exploration and Technology]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Contribute to the blog, or Silence will fall]

Comment: I see this pic everywhere... where is it from?

Comment: @OghmaOsiris it's the [the silence from Doctor Who Series 6](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b0103y2x/profiles/the-silence)

Answer (score 8):

[image: Movies.Stackexchange]

Comment: because, you know, questions!

Answer (score 7):

[image: Visit the new Chess Stack Exchange site]

Comment: I think you may have the wrong site. Try, http://meta.chess.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @OghmaOsiris, This is actually the site I intended. We're just trying to up awareness of the new chess beta by posting ads at some of the graduated SE sites that might have interested users. (See e.g. our more successful posting over at Arqade: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/5001/28435). If it's less welcome here, well, so be it :-)

Comment: I'm all for chess. I love me some hex chess. But this thread is for SciFi.SE.com ads. If you'd like to just pop in and get people aware of the site, you can go to chat and mention it there.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris, It was (and still is) my understanding that beta SE sites routinely advertise themselves on other SE sites. (That seems to be backed up by the fact that our ad has been substantially upvoted at every other community promotion meta question where we've so far put it: Arqade, Super User, GameDev.) In any case, it is each community's decision what ads it wants to show, and I'm perfectly happy if y'all choose not to show ours. I hope I didn't bother/offend anyone with our posting; it was certainly not my intent.

Comment: While there is no rule forbidding unrelated ads, this isn't really what they are intended for. The objective here is to advertise things that are relevant to the community. See the official response on [Appropriate content for community ads](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147312/appropriate-content-for-community-ads). (Cc @OghmaOsiris)

Answer (score 7):

[image: Submit to the blog and the Doctor will be spared]

Comment: For the love of font! This isn't 1996 anymore lol

Comment: I submitted this entry via fax (http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2009-12-10/)

Comment: This is plain wrong. DALEKS DO NOT SPARE THE DOCTOR!!!

Answer (score 7):

[image: Website Seeks new Blog Posts]

Answer (score 7):

[image: One Blog to Post Them]

Comment: The lettering needs a lot of work to look like a presentable ad.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris Please feel free to create a better version and edit the answer. I'll do my best to improve it, but sadly my graphic design skills are mediocre on a good day.

Answer (score 6):

[image: Save the SciFi]

Answer (score 3):

[image: What if I told you, we had a blog?]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Could you contribute to the Blog, Pleeease]

Comment: Other than the desperation in the plea, I like it.