# Community Promotion Ads - 2013

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It's been about a year now, so it is now time for the reboot of the Community Promotion Ads!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- interesting articles or findings for the curious
- cool Science Fiction or Fantasy events/conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/2484).

Comment: What is the allowed dpi?

Comment: @OghmaOsiris I don't think there's a limitation, as long as you can fit it within 150 KB, as specified above.

Answer (score 21):

[image: Memory-Alpha.org *Star Trek* Wiki![][1]]

Answer (score 18):

[image: Anime & Manga SE]

Comment: Suggestions are welcome. :)

Comment: Should look less awesome; You're showing us up!

Comment: @Pureferret ahah :D thanks for the compliment. We're discussing about it [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/anime-and-manga) if you have some observation/remark.

Comment: We decided over at [Anime & Manga](http://anime.stackexchange.com) that we will rotate the image that appears here, so that we can show all our ads without 'flooding' your site with them. Thus, we will change the image on the post every week or so.

Comment: Love the [Itachi ad](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/2535/4). Maybe you could put it in Arqade's Community Ads too.

Comment: @galacticninja Thank you! *bows* Actually I already did, but deleted it. I might re-put it these days. Or wait until community ads 2014. :P

Answer (score 15):

[image: Space Exploration Stack Exchange]

Answer (score 14):

[image: robotics stack exchange]

Answer (score 13):

[image: Save the SciFi]

Comment: This looks like a really cool project.

Answer (score 12):

[image: Itachi, birds version]

Answer (score 12):

[image: robotics stack exchange]

Comment: <3 zim - did you draw gir?

Comment: @Omega - I'm afraid that I'm not that talented, but I am very grateful to [Daniel T. McDonald](http://www.elfwood.com/~captainzero/GIR-2.0.2597782.html) for placing this image in the public domain.

Answer (score 11):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Answer (score 10):

[image: Movies.Stackexchange]

Comment: brought my ad over to 2013 to see if it still gets some luvin.

Comment: And luvin it will get.

Answer (score 9):

[image: OBEY THE EYE! Visit Anime & Manga SE!]

Comment: ... YES, MY LORD.

Answer (score 9):

[image: Space Exploration Stack Exchange]

Answer (score 8):

[image: PRECIOUS - theonering.net]

Answer (score 7):

[image: Writing exercise chat]

Answer (score 5):

[image: THE BOY WHO LIVED - THE LEAKY CAULDRON]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Answer (score 4):

[image: THE HARRY POTTER LEXICON]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Anime & Manga SE Community on FB]

Answer (score 3):

[image: ORIGINAL JK ROWLING WEBSITE - TEXT ONLY - WAYBACK MACHINE - TONS OF GOOD HARRY POTTER INFO]

Comment: Is the image also implying that when you finally find it, it could be fake? :)

Answer (score 3):

[image: Anime & Manga SE Community on G+]

Answer (score 1):

[image: TO BOLDLY GO 2013]

Comment: You Copycat! ;P

Comment: I was just poking fun. I made a Tardis ad, too.

Answer (score -2):

[image: ORIGINAL JK ROWLING WEBSITE - TEXT ONLY - WAYBACK MACHINE - TONS OF GOOD HARRY POTTER INFO]

Comment: An alternate version to the Horcrux ad for J.K. Rowling's orginal website. The artist is Llithium and is credited up the left side of the picture in a very faint font.

Answer (score -4):

[image: THE WORST SORT OF MUGGLES - MUGGLENET PROMO]

Comment: Funny, but it... kind of discourages me to click it lol.