# Clarification needed regarding what URL to use in the Community Promotion ads?

Tags: discussion

I'm wondering what URL are we supposed to be using for the Community Promotion ads? All my ads, and others' as well, were unilaterally deleted with a message from Gilles stating "It is useless to advertise SFF on the site itself". Which, of course it would be. **WHAT URL ARE WE SUPPOSED TO BE USING IN THE CODE OF THE ADS?**

[image: FRUSTRATION!]

In the [original Community Promotion Ads post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2484/community-promotion-ads-2013/2500#2500) it says *Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the **main site**, in the right sidebar.*

Does this mean the main site StackExchange.com or SciFi.stackexchange.com.

1. Where exactly are these ads to be placed?
2. **WHAT URL ARE WE TO USE?**
3. Would it be possible to receive an explanation such as "Cool ad, but you've got the wrong URL. The URL you need to be using for the clickthrough is "blahblahblah.blah.com"" and time to make a correction before an auto delete?
4. Could "Main site" be clarified?

I would appreciate some guidance here because I had the same problem with the blog advertisements. An explanation of the clickthrough URL was never forthcoming.

I will say that when I did a community advertisement last year, in 2011, and it was voted up, it appeared on the MAIN site: StackExchange.com with a link ***to*** SciFi.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I guess it isn't apparent what you are asking then...clearly **what URL to use** is the URL you want to advertise. Since these go on the main SciFi site though, there is no point in advertising it is there?

Comment: My question was apparent to Pearsonartphoto, who readily provided exactly the answer that I needed.

Comment: Well you apparently didn't understand my answer then, which like Pearsonartphoto's explains that the ads are on the main site, and are superfluous(not meant to promote this community), since they are **on** this community's main site.

Comment: @NominSim it's obvious to some, but 'Community Promotion ads' to me, even, normally means promoting this community.

Comment: @Pureferret I realized that it wasn't obvious...but I answered her question by stating that the advertisement only happens on the main site (SciFi.SE) so any advertising done for the main site is redundant. She then commented that my answer *didn't* answer her question...but PearsonArtPhoto's answer is saying essentially the same thing...i.e. the Community promo ads aren't to promote the community(The SciFi.SE site).

Comment: I am upvoting because I was under the impression we were supposed to create ads for SciFi.SE, and they'd appear elsewhere.  Apparently I, too, had it backwards...

Comment: @NominSim -- Well, *I* get to decide who answers my questions effectively and I don't want to get into a protracted argument about it.

Comment: @Slytherincess...hence why I deleted my answer when you said it didn't answer your question(not that it didn't answer effectively, that it didn't answer, period).  I admit I was a little amazed that when Pearson answered saying something very similar to mine you not only accepted it as an answer (which of course you are entitled to do) but also **specifically brought it to my attention**. It seemed rather childish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Community promotion ads aren't to promote this community, they are things that this community wants to promote. If you want to promote this community, I suggest you create a thread devoted to that, along with suggestions as to which other sites might be relevant.

Comment: Ahhhhhhh! **THIS** is what I needed to know. *Now* I understand. I can create little ads to promote, say, The Leaky Cauldron, to share that site with other people *in* the SFF.se community. I totally understand now and I truly thank you for clarifying this. This is great! :D :D :D