# Reverse Community Promotion Ads 2013

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I noticed there is a fair amount of suggested [Community Promotion Ads](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2484/2565) that was rightfully discarded (i.e. mod-deleted) because it advertises the main site. I agree that this is redundant, since the ads would be shown on the main site itself, but some of the posts might have merit for other SE sites. So, maybe we could collect suggestions for other sites on the SE network as answers to this question. Maybe it sparks an idea where those outcast ads might fit.

Answer (score 3):

[image: ONE RING TO RULE THEM ALL]

Comment: Original poster: [a Slytherin](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/users/3500/a-slytherin)

Answer (score 2):

[image: SCI FI BANNER 2013]

Comment: Original poster: [a Slytherin](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/users/3500/a-slytherin)

Answer (score 2):

[image: TO BOLDLY GO 2013]

Comment: Original poster: [a Slytherin](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/users/3500/a-slytherin)

Answer (score 2):

[image: PRECIOUS 2013]

Comment: Original poster: [a Slytherin](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/users/3500/a-slytherin)

Answer (score 2):

[image: That's no moon]

Comment: Original poster: [OghmaOsiris](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/2501/revisions)

Answer (score 2):

[image: Not sure if SciFi Or Fantasy]

Comment: Original poster: [OghmaOsiris](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/2501/revisions)

Answer (score 2):

[image: It's bigger on the inside]

Comment: Original poster: [OghmaOsiris](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/2501/revisions)

Answer (score 2):

[image: Scientist. Fictional.]

Comment: Posted on [Arqade](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/6881/10310) (i.e. Gaming.SE).

Answer (score -1):

[image: Ask your lore questions on scifi.stackexchange]

Comment: Posted on [Arqade](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/5357/452) (i.e. Gaming.SE).

Comment: Note: This was posted on the Arqade-CPA 2012 but not reposted on 2013 (but we could do this depending on the votes it gets here).